# Difference between UTC, GMT and Daylight saving time in JS

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

I already read a lot of post and a little confused with UTC, GMT and daylight saving time.

Anyone can explain about javascript `Date()` object with UTC, GMT and daylight saving time.

The main point I want to know is, when we work with date, we need to think or not about daylight saving time.

And the calculation of UTC,GMT and daylight saving time is same or not in different kind of programming languages.

Comment: This is a bit broad. What specifically are you trying to accomplish? What's got you confused?

Comment: UTC and GMT are the same for all practical purposes.  DST doesn't apply to either.  Other than that, your questions are too broad.  Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) is a standard, [GMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time) is a time zone. UTC uses the same offset as GMT, i.e. +00:00. They are essentially interchangeable when discussing offsets.

All javascript (ECMAScript) Date objects use a time value that is UTC milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. When the Date constructor is called without any arguments, it gets the time and time zone offset from the host system and calculates the time value. Therefore, the accuracy of the generated date depends on the accuracy of those components.

When outputting date values using the UTC methods (e.g. getUTCHours, getUTCMinutes, etc.), the vaules are UTC (GMT). When not using those methods (e.g. getHours, getMinutes, etc.) the host system time zone offset is used with the time value to generate "local" values from the UTC time value.

Whether daylight saving is applied or not depends on the host system settings. Whatever the current rules are for the host system time zone changes for daylight saving are applied to all dates, regardless of the actual offset that date (e.g. if currently DST starts on the first Sunday in October then it will be assumed to have always started on the first Sunday in October).

Date object behaviour is described in [ECMA-262 §20.3.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-constructor) and a bit more clearly (for some parts) in [MDN Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: Downvotes without an explanation are pointless. It doesn't help me improve the answer or convince me to delete it if inappropriate.